# How to change a background color in Javascript based on an entered value

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to create a page that, upon entering a temperature of or higher than 70, the result page will turn red, and if the temperature is below 70, then it will turn blue. I already have a sample page for the first part of the code for the submit page. I just don't want the words to turn colors, I want the entire page to turn colors based on the temperature. Can anyone help?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['temperature'])): //isset determines if var has valid contents, even empty string

    //if var is set, show what it contains
    $myFahrenheit = (int)$_POST['temperature']; //cast value sent via post to an integer

    $myCelsius = intval(($myFahrenheit-32) * (5/9)); //calc celsius
    echo '<h1><font color="blue">You entered ' . $myFahrenheit . ' in Fahrenheit!!</font><br />';
    echo '<h1><font color="red"> It is '. $myCelsius .' in celsius!!</font><br />';
    //put link on page to reset form
    print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">Reset page</a>';
else:
    //show form
?>
    <!--Note the server variable indicating the page we are on -->
    <form action="<? print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    Enter your temperature in Fahrenheit <input type="text" name="temperature"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Show me the temperature in celsius!!">
    </form>
<?
endif;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess a simple `<body>` styling will work here?

```
<html>
<?php
    $style = '';
    if (isset($_POST['temperature']))
    {
        if ($_POST['temperature'] >= 70)
            $style = 'background-color: red;';
        else
            $style = 'background-color: blue;';
    }
?>
<body style="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($style); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
<html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['temperature'])) //isset determines if var has valid contents, even empty string
{//if var is set, show what it contains
$myFahrenheit = (int)$_POST['temperature']; //cast value sent via post to an integer
if($myFahrenheit > 70)
   echo "<body style='background-color:red;'>";
else
   echo "<body style='background-color:blue;'>";
$myCelsius = intval(($myFahrenheit-32) * (5/9)); //calc celsius
 echo '<h1><font color="blue">You entered ' . $myFahrenheit . ' in Fahrenheit!!    </font><br />';
echo '<h1><font color="red"> It is '. $myCelsius .' in celsius!!</font><br />';
//put link on page to reset form
print '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">Reset page</a>';
}else{ //show form
?>
```

Comment: @getlaura i have edited the code , check it now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($myFahrenheit > 70)
  echo '<script>document.body.style.background = "red";</script>';
else
  echo '<script>document.body.style.background = "blue";</script>';
```

Comment: I can't see why you would need to use PHP to output JavaScript that modifies the CSS of HTML elements...

Comment: Great! That worked! I'm in a class and still learning. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wait, when did the question become about JavaScript? The OP was edited? I guess my quick answer got invalidated.